# C++ cin vs. C sscanf

Tags: c++, c, stringstream, cin, scanf

So i wrote this in C, so sscanf scans in s but then discards it, then scans in d and stores it. So if the input is "Hello 007", Hello is scanned but discarded and 007 is stored in d.

```
static void cmd_test(const char *s)
{
    int d = maxdepth;
    sscanf(s, "%*s%d", &d);
}
```

So, my question is how can I do the same thing but in C++? possibly using stringstream?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```c
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

static void cmd_test(const char *s)
{
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    std::string dummy;
    int d = maxdepth;
    iss >> dummy >> d;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't really extract into an anonymous string, but you can just make a dummy and ignore it:

```
#include <string>
#include <istream>
// #include <sstream> // see below

void cmd_test(std::istream & iss) // any std::istream will do!
{

  // alternatively, pass a `const char * str` as the argument,
  // change the above header inclusion, and declare:
  // std::istringstream iss(str);

  int d;
  std::string s;

  if (!(iss >> s >> d)) { /* maybe handle error */ }

  // now `d` holds your value if the above succeeded
}
```

Note that the extraction might fail, whence the conditional I put in. It's up to you what you do in case of an error; the C++ thing to do would be to throw an exception (though if your actual function communicates errors already, you might be able to just `return` an error).

Example usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
  cmd_test(std::cin);

  std::ifstream infile("myfile.txt");
  cmd_test(infile);

  std::string s = get_string_from_user();
  std::istringstream iss(s);
  cmd_test(iss);
}
```

Comment: Maybe the change of the argument from `const char*` to a `istringstream` is a bit heavy?

Comment: @ChristianRau: Who knows... the OP seems to be on the case regarding string streams, perhaps he already has a stream lying around somewhere. If not you can construct one from a `const char*` if you prefer. I added a comment.

Comment: @KerrekSB Good point, in practice I would actually prefer a stream argument, too. But in this case a general istream would even be better.

Comment: @KerrekSB But now the change is really heavy. You might at least show him an example how to call this function when he only has a char* or a string (and maybe change the header to istream, too).

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

static void cmd_test(const std::string &s)
{
    int d = maxdepth;
    std::string dont_care;
    std::istringstream in(s);
    in >> dont_care >> d;
}
```